# Resizing a dataframe to account for new values that are extracted from a json in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have extracted data via the github API and then used json.normalise to flatten the data into a dataframe. Unfortunately, some of the data is still in nested dictoinaries in the column. I'm able to extract the value from the dictionary but the problem comes in when there is more than one dictionary in the cell.

[image]

How do I manipulate the dataframe so that it resizes to account for the additional values.

Like this:

[image: desired outcome]

Comment: You can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on the column. For the future, you [should not post code or data as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), but paste your actual code or image into your question. This way, you enable users to troubleshoot your problem in their local environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your problem, let's suppose we have this dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
                   'Pull.Request.Files.Nodes': [[{'path':'example 1'}], [{'path':'example 2'}, {'path':'example 3'}]],
                   })
```

```
df
   ID                        Pull.Request.Files.Nodes
0   1                         [{'path': 'example 1'}]
1   2  [{'path': 'example 2'}, {'path': 'example 3'}]
```

We could explode the column `'Pull.Request.Files.Nodes'` to extract dictionaries from list, and then we could apply a lambda function, like this :

```py
df = df.explode('Pull.Request.Files.Nodes', ignore_index=True)
df['Pull.Request.Files.Nodes'] = df['Pull.Request.Files.Nodes'].apply(lambda r:r['path'])
```

**Complete code**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
                   'Pull.Request.Files.Nodes': [[{'path':'example 1'}], [{'path':'example 2'}, {'path':'example 3'}]],
                   })

df = df.explode('Pull.Request.Files.Nodes', ignore_index=True)
df['Pull.Request.Files.Nodes'] = df['Pull.Request.Files.Nodes'].apply(lambda r:r['path'])

#    ID Pull.Request.Files.Nodes
# 0   1                example 1
# 1   2                example 2
# 2   2                example 3
```

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the good question. I suggest you post code instead of images, you would then have more answers like that... From my experience on SO.